# Why do some python scripts begin with #!/usr/bin/env python?

Tags: scripts, python

I noticed that some python scripts start with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

instead of

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Are python scripts the only ones that use `#!/usr/bin/env`? Are there any scripts that start out with for example `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env perl`? If not then why are python scripts different?

Comment: Exact http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script

Comment: The shebang should read `#!`, not `#`.

Comment: Also [Why is it better to use “#!/usr/bin/env NAME” instead of “#!/path/to/NAME” as my shebang?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/23408) (on U&L)

Answer (score 71):

#### Using env in the shebang of a script

Python scripts are not different from scripts in any other language on this.

Either the usage of `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/python` plays a role if the script is *executable*, and called without the preceding language. The script then calls the language's interpreter to run the code inside the script, and the shebang is the "guide" to find, in your example, `python`.

Using `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of the absolute (full path) `#!/usr/bin/python` makes sure python (or any other language's interpreter) is found, in case it might not be in exactly the same location across different Linux- or Unix -like distributions, as explained e.g. [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/finding-bash-perl-python-portably-using-env.html).

Although `#!/usr/bin/python` will work on a default Ubuntu system, it is therefore good practice to use  `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead.

#### About env

`env` is an executable in `/usr/bin`, *or*, as mentioned by @hvd (thanks for the hint!), available as a compatibility symlink in `/usr/bin` to `env`, in pretty much all Linux distributions.

From **Wikipedia**:

---

*env is a shell command for Unix and Unix-like operating systems. It is used to either print a list of environment variables or run another utility in an altered environment without having to modify the currently existing environment. Using env, variables may be added or removed, and existing variables may be changed by assigning new values to them.*

and in relation to your question:

*In practice, env has another common use. It is often used by shell scripts to launch the correct interpreter. In this usage, the environment is typically not changed*

---

More on `env` is to be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Env), and, as always, in `man env` (from a terminal).

---

#### Additional information on the shebang; why doesn't #!python work?

In a comment, it was asked why we cannot simply use `#!python` as a shebang. Since the interpreter is in `$PATH`, the idea is understandable.

The reason is that an executable is executed by `execve`, as we can read [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve). Specifically the lines:

*An interpreter script is a text file that has execute permission enabled and whose first line is of the form:*

`#! interpreter [optional-arg]`

*The interpreter must be a* ***valid pathname*** *for an executable....*

explain that `execve` demands a full (valid) path to the interpreter. That makes sense, since scripts (in any language) can e.g. be run at any moment during startup as well, possibly before `$PATH` is set at all.

Comment: For completeness, since this isn't really specific to Ubuntu, there is no formal requirement for `/usr/bin/env` to exist any more than there is a requirement for `/usr/bin/python` to exist. It could legitimately exist as `/bin/env`, for instance. It's just that in practice, pretty much every distro makes `env` available as `/usr/bin/env`, either directly or through a compatibility symlink.

Comment: @rbialon Thanks for fixing my silly copy- paste mistakes :) !

Comment: @hvd Luckily, or we would have needed an `env` for `env`. :)

Comment: In regular bash scripts, you start with #!/bin/bash so that the script knows what interpeter to use. In your case, it is so your script knows to use the python interepter. That's the easy answer.

Comment: Just as a tip, you should always do #!/usr/bin/env python2 or #!/usr/bin/env python3. You should always make your Python scripts use a specific version of the interpreter rather than putting just 'python'.

Comment: Why can't we use `#!python`?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju see my updated answer.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, So basically, all of this problem would not have been, if `#!` has some common sense to read variables instead of insisting on absoluteness.

Answer (score 25):

Jacob's answer explains it well. However there is one more point I would like to mention.

Using `/usr/bin/env/` in python serves one more purpose. As python supports *virtual environments*, using `/usr/bin/env python` will make sure that your scripts runs inside the virtual environment, if you are inside one.
Whereas, `/usr/bin/python` will run outside the virtual environment.

Comment: What is python's "virtual environment" all about?

Comment: "virtual environment" is a way to create application-specific custom deployments of Python, each with its own packages installed, without affecting the system-wide default installation.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the answers given above, the use of `/usr/bin/env` allows your Python to be installed in non-standard places, and as long as your `PATH` is set-up correctly, the script will run unmodified on any UNIX-style system that has `/usr/bin/env`. This includes any modern version of Linux and OS/X.

Comment: How is this any different from  a symlink for `/use/bin/python`?

Comment: The user might not have permission to create such a symlink in /usr/bin, and the developer should not assume it. Also, it's possible that several Python distributions are installed side by side, and using /usr/bin/env one could choose which one to run by altering the PATH variable.