# Make virtualenv and activate it with shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, virtualenv

I want to make shell script that makes virtualenv, activates it, install some libraries and run python script with it.

But I have problem that I can't activate virtualenv in shell script unless i do "source script.sh" but then python3 doesn't work. 
How can I do something like this?

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
python3 -m virtualenv virtual
source virtual/bin/activate
pip install <some libraries>
python <filename.py>
```

I would like to do this without any global paths to python. I want it to work locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with Ubuntu (and most other Linux distros I’d say) it’s safe to use the absolute paths as Python is an essential component of the OS:

```
/usr/bin/python   # or respectively
/usr/bin/python3
```

If you don’t want to run the systemwide installed Python version, but rather the one first in the calling user’s `PATH`, instead use:

```
/usr/bin/env python   # or respectively
/usr/bin/env python3
```

#### Further reading about this alternative

- [Why do some python scripts begin with #!/usr/bin/env python?](https://askubuntu.com/q/716280/507051)
- [What type of path in shebang is more preferable?](https://askubuntu.com/q/88257/507051)